# How to make month over month Dynamic? below script is hard coded January and february

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
WITH ctetable AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        [site id],
        DATENAME(MONTH, [wcp_createddate]) AS MonthNames
    FROM   
        [dbo].[getsiteharveyballscores]
)
SELECT 
    *,
   january + february AS Combine,
   IIF((january + february) = 1
        AND february = 0, 'Drop', IIF((january + february) = 1
                                     AND february = 1, 'New', 'Continue')) AS Flag
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         monthnames,
         [site id] AS SiteId,
         [site id]
     FROM   
         ctetable) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (COUNT([site id])   
         FOR monthnames IN (january, february)) AS pivottable;
```

Comment: If you want a question to be answered, then sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of the logic, and an appropriate database tag all increase the likelihood of getting an answer.

Comment: How many columns do you need to pivot? Is it just fixed to the 12 months, or are we going over into years